# text GHC only, aeson Portable?

Tags: haskell

The [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package is marked as GHC-only, whereas the [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) package is marked as Portable. However, `aeson` relies on Data.Text.Internal, which is in the `text` package. But if `text` is GHC-only, then surely `aeson` must be too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Portability/Stability tags aren't really taken too seriously most of the time, there's no community standard as to how they are used. `aeson` certainly isn't portable across Haskell implementations, since it uses Template Haskell, which is only available on GHC. I would assume, however, that it is portable across platforms (i.e. Mac, Windows, Linux), so my guess is it uses the term in a different sense to the way `text` does.